# Angular showing data after http request complete

Tags: angularjs

Hello I am using following code. I am getting data from http get request during fetching data it is showing `<h2> No detail found</h2>` then after fetching data from server it is showing the fetched data in list.

I want to avoid showing `<h2> No detail found</h2>`  before http get request complete.

```
<div ng-controller="expCont">
     <ul>
        <div  ng-repeat="n in expenses">
         <li class="list-group-item">
           {{n.name}}{{n.price}}
         </li>
        </div>
       </ul>  
      <div ng-show="!expenses.length">
            <h2> No detail found</h2>                       
      </div>
</div>
```

How to do this.

Comment: <div ng-show="expenses.length !=0 ">
            <h2> No detail found</h2>                       
      </div>

Comment: @jose I think, you meant `<div ng-show="expenses.length ==0 "> <h2> No detail found</h2> </div>`

Comment: When do you want to show `<h2> No detail found</h2>`?

Comment: @fshock after getting http resonse

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)</kbd>

```
<div ng-if='expenses'>
   <ul>
    <div  ng-repeat="n in expenses">
     <li class="list-group-item">
       {{n.name}}{{n.price}}
     </li>
    </div>
   </ul>  
  <div ng-show="!expenses.length">
        <h2> No detail found</h2>                       
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different approach:

In your controller:

```
  app.controller('expCont', function($scope) {
      $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.getData = function() {
          $scope.loading = true;
          //your http request
           $scope.loading = false;
        };
        $scope.getData();
      })
```

In template:

```
   <div ng-controller="expCont">
         <ul>
             <li ng-if="!loading && expenses.length > 0" ng-repeat="n in expenses" class="list-group-item">
               {{n.name}}{{n.price}}
             </li>
           </ul>  
          <div ng-if="expenses.length == 0 && !loading">
                <h2> No detail found</h2>                       
          </div>
          <div ng-if="loading">
                <h2> Loading...</h2>                       
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
<div ng-show="expenses != NULL && expenses != undefined && expenses.length === 0">
  <h2> No detail found</h2>                       
</div>
```